# gstreamer connecting rtpsession to multiudpsink

Tags: android, gstreamer

I'm very new to gstreamer. My pipeline (which uses Android camera) in gst_parse_launch is:

```
"ahcsrc ! videoconvert ! amcvidenc-omxqcomvideoencoderavc bitrate=6000000 i-frame-interval=2"
" ! rtph264pay config-interval=-1" 
" ! .send_rtp_sink rtpsession name=session .send_rtpsrc ! multiudpsink sync=false async=false name=rtpudpsinkvideo clients=%s"
" ! session.send_rtcp_sink session.send_rtpsrc ! multiudpsink sync=false async=false name=rtcpudpsinkvideo clients=%s"
```

Whenever I'm trying to send RTP packets I'm getting "could not link rtpudpsinkvideo to session" error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by shoving the rtpsession in the same way this guy did it https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/knowledge/rtp_streaming.html

I also removed the sdes part because gstreamer couldn't parse it but I think it just me not knowing what is it to begin with.

The pipeline now looks like this:

```
"rtpsession name=r"
"ahcsrc ! videoconvert ! amcvidenc-omxqcomvideoencoderavc bitrate=6000000 i-frame-interval=2"
" ! rtph264pay config-interval=-1" 
" ! r.send_rtp_sink"
" r.send_rtp_src ! multiudpsink sync=false async=false name=rtpudpsinkvideo clients=%s"
" r.send_rtcp_src ! multiudpsink sync=false async=false name=rtcpudpsinkvideo clients=%s"
```